# How to alter the background size of the images in a javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slideshow

I have a basic slideshow, 3 pictures, that cycle automatically at a 2.5 second interval. However, the slideshow is only in the top of my webpage, so it stretches the picture. I am attempting to set the image size to full and use image sprites to align the image to my liking. Currently the slideshow is working but the images remain stretched. Is there a way to make the images in the slide show not stretch?

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.bgpic {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

#pict {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('/Junk/1.jpg') 0 -150px;    
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var image1 = new Image()
    image1.src="/Junk/1.jpg";
    var image2 = new Image()
    image2.src="/Junk/2.jpg";
    var image3 = new Image()
    image3.src="/Junk/3.jpg";
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="bgpic">
<img src="/Junk/1.jpg" id="pict" name="slide" style="-webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var step=1;
    function slideit() {
    if(!document.images)
    return;
    document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
    document.getElementById("pict").style.backgroundSize="cover";
    if (step<3){
    step++;
    }
    else {
    step=1;
    }
    setTimeout("slideit()", 2500)
    }
    slideit();
</script>
</div>
</body>
```

Nothing I have tried has worked. Please help.

Comment: use `contain` instead of `cover` if you dont want it stretched

Comment: Before I added the slideshow, I had the image exactly how i wanted it using `cover`. The problem is that the javascript slideshow is not recognizing that i want the pictures to be `cover` so they remain stretched.

Comment: background-size only works with background-image, it doesn't affect the display of an image that is loaded in an img src, and your img element gets stretched because you are setting a percentage width/height in your css

Comment: Ok, is there any work around?

Comment: yea instead of setting the image .src set the style for background-image: `element.style.backgroundImage="url(http://some.url.to.image.com/someimage.jpg)";`, also why are you using eval to do string concatenation?